# Plus button not displaying text user writes

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my code right now. I've tried tons of ways but none of them have worked.

After clicking the plus button and writing the text and clicking "add" it should display what has been written but nothing shows up.

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @State private var newLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var isAddingLanding = false
    @State private var landings: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.3)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Landing!")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { _ in 0 }
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                            .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in 0 }
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack {
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Button(action: {
                                    isAddingLanding = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .position(x: geometry.size.width - 30, y: 30)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                    LandingNameView(newLandingName: newLandingName)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {
                    if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                        landings.append(newLandingName)
                    }
                    newLandingName = ""
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Enter landing name: \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding()
                        
                        Button("Add") {
                            if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                                landings.append(newLandingName)
                                newLandingName = ""
                            }
                            isAddingLanding = false
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings"))
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to get text to show once user writes it.

Answer (score 0):

First, reorganize your view hierarchy.

> This is my code right now. I've tried tons of ways but none of them have worked. After clicking the plus button, writing the text, and clicking "add" it should display what has been written but nothing shows up.

It's not showing up because the following element has no text inside

```swift
List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in }
// Change it to
List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in Text(landing) }
```

And this element is not in the correct view hierarchy. Place it like this.

```swift
struct LandingView: View {
    @State private var newLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var isAddingLanding = false
    @State private var landings: [String] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle().scale(1.7).foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
                Circle().scale(1.3).foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Landing!")
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { _ in 0 }
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                            .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in 0 }
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack {
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Button(action: { isAddingLanding = true }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus").frame(width: 20, height: 20).foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .position(x: geometry.size.width - 30, y: 30)
                            }
                        }.padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                    List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in Text(landing) }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings"))
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Enter landing name: \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                        Button("Add") {
                            if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                                landings.append(newLandingName)
                                newLandingName = ""
                            }
                            isAddingLanding = false
                        }
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```